# Minimal, maximal, least, and greatest element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, maximal-subgroup

Let $B = \{1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 18\}$ and $R$ be defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x|y$.

a)  Determine all minimal and all maximal elements of the poset.
b)  Find all least and greatest elements of the poset.

I am most confused about minimal, but here is what I have for an explanation and an answer. Am I on the right track?

MAXIMAL: Cannot be made to divide a bigger number; it is not less than another element. Answer: $12$ and $18$
MINIMAL: Can be made to divide a bigger number; it is less than another element. Answer: $1$
GREATEST: One number that every other element divides into. Answer: There is no one single number.
LEAST: One number that divides into every other element. Answer: $1$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to know if I am on the right track with my answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Great! Thank you for the confirmation!